# Align these elements side by side in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

i downloaded a plugin in wordpress called WP Hotel Booking using Divi Theme Builder.

This is his actual design in my site:

[image]

How can i align these elements side by side like this?

[image: image2]

I guess the problem is since its a wordpress theme and i didnt created that one, i can only use css to try do these changes.

This is the actual website if needed to try with console: http://198.199.66.183/ (yep, no domain yet)
These are the css class:

```
.hb_input_date_check {
/* arrival/departure date*/
}
.entry-content .hotel-booking-search select {
/* adults/children */
}
.entry-content .hotel-booking-search form button {
/* the button */
}
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

Inside your custom styles for this respective website, add these styles to the parent wrapper of the form. I've tested this with your current code & theme, and it appears to work:

```
.hb-form-table {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

What this will do is ensure that the items are in a flexible container, not allowing them to go to the next row. Some additional CSS will be required to ensure that the input fields all have the same padding, and height(s). If you're new to flex-box, here's a full guide on how to use it, along with all of it's attributes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hey, it works but gets broken in mobile.
Should i make a breakpoint to this specific css rule?

Comment: I did some work:
   @media (min-width: 1025px) { 

   .hb-form-table {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }
    }


But its not centered in the page, what can i do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, on mobile you will have to reset the display property for them to stack on-top of one another (since mobile devices do not have enough room for all the content to fit in their widths). To do this, add display:block to the property with your break-point, overwriting the flex-box display property.